# Progress-bar con datos de SQL

Tags: html, bootstrap

Buenas tengo un progress bar de bootstap 3.

```
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="70" style="width: 70px"> </div>
  </div>
```

Mi idea es que tengo un `count` que me saca el numero total de pedidos que hay en la bd. Luego tengo otro `count` con los pedidos que tienen un estado de `pichado` = 1.

Entonces mi idea es que el valor total de el progress bar sea el primer `count`, y la barra de progreso sea sea el segundo `count`. De este modo la barra de progreso su valor seria por ejemplo 150 pedidos pero solo pinchados =1 70 pedidos.

No se si se puede hacer un progress-bar donde ponga cada valor en su sitio, ya que las progress-bar que encuentro el tamaño va en relación a un width: % .

Alguna sugerencia de como hacerlo?? gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regla de tres.

```js
var total=150;
var pichado =70;
var porcentaje=(pichado *100)/total;
document.getElementById("barra").style.width=porcentaje+"%";
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" id="barra"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta @HERRERA , pero eso es javascript no, como meto la variable de `php` ahí? gracias

Comment: Puedes hacer la misma ecuacion count2*100/count1 y ponerla en el estilo del width,

Comment: No se como hacerlo, puedes mostrar un ejemplo con `php` gracias @HERRERA

Comment: style="width:<?= $calculo ?>%">, ahora la variable "calculo" es la regla de 3 de tus datos

Comment: No lo entiendo, puedes modificar la respuesta por favor @HERRERA ?

Comment: Nada ya lo tengo `var total= ( "<?php echo $tot; ?>" );` gracias por tu ayuda!